# It is Possible to use Bing Maps in flutter app

Tags: flutter, bing-maps, bing, azure-maps, fluttermap

I want to use `Bing Maps` in `Flutter` with all properties like current location and custom marker.

It is Possible to use Bing Maps in flutter app?
I want to use a flutter package that it supports android, ios and web.
For example by `flutter_map` package can I use Bing Maps?
Anybody has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to load Bing Maps tiles as a layer within the open source Flutter Map SDK. https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map

To use Bing Maps you first have to call the Imagery metadata service to register the map session and to get the latest map tile URLs as per this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/directly-accessing-the-bing-maps-tiles

From there you can use the map tile URL as a tile layer within the flutter map SDK like the other examples.

Alternatively, you may also want to consider using Azure Maps in this case. Licensing is much easier, the data is pretty much the same as Bing Maps, and billing is based on map tile consumption which can be much cheaper than session based pricing as map tiles automatically get cached. There is an Azure Maps example in the map README page for the Flutter Map SDK.